# check input outside class from a function?

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector as mysql


class Reservation:
```

I basically created a class Reservation which has its airplane and hotel check in functions,
the users name,surname,id in the end are inserted into a table in mysql

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.passenger_id = int(input("Put your id "))
        self.passenger_fname = str(input("Your name "))
        self.passenger_lname = str(input("Your last name "))
        self.expenses = 0
        self.airline_seats = {"Business Class":10,
                              "First Class":15,
                              "Economy":20}

        self.airplane_prices = {"Business Class":1000,
                              "First Class":1500,
                              "Economy":2000}

        self.hotel_room = {"Penthouse":2,
                           "Queen Bedroom":15,
                           "King Bedroom":20
                           }

        self.hotel_prices = {"Penthouse":500,
                           "Queen Bedroom":250,
                           "King Bedroom":150}







    def airplane_cost(self):
        status = True
        while(status):

            try:
                airplane_input= input("Choose: Business Class:1000,First Class:1500, Economy:2000 ")
                for bed,value in self.airplane_prices.items():

                    if bed == airplane_input:
                        self.expenses += value
                        status = False
                        break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)





    def hotel_cost(self):
        status = True

        while(status):

            try:
                hotel_choice_input = input("You want to check in")

                if hotel_choice_input == "yes" or hotel_choice_input=="Yes":

                    hotel_choice_input = input("Choose: Penthouse:500, Queen Bedroom:250,King Bedroom:150 ")
                    for room,value in self.hotel_prices.items():
                        if hotel_choice_input == room:
                            self.expenses += value
                            status = False
                            break
                elif hotel_choice_input == "No" or hotel_choice_input == "no":
                    print("Okay have a nice day")
                    status = False
                    break

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


    def check_expenses(self):
        print("Your cost is",self.expenses)



c = Reservation()
c.airplane_cost()
c.hotel_cost()
c.check_expenses()

db = mysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd="1234",
    database="airplaneDb"
)


cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)

# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE  Airplane1 (name VARCHAR(50),lastname VARCHAR(50), id int)")
# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE  Hotel1 (name VARCHAR(50),lastname VARCHAR(50), id int)")

sql = "INSERT INTO Airplane1 (name,lastname,id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
sql1 = "INSERT INTO Hotel1 (name,lastname,id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
val = (c.passenger_fname,c.passenger_lname,c.passenger_id)
cursor.execute(sql,val)
```

My question is how do i check if hotel_check_input is "yes" or "no" from outside the class?

Because if the user says no for a check in hotel, i dont want his name,surname,id added to the table in mysql and if he says yes then yes

```
cursor.execute(sql1,val)
db.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Airplane1")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Hotel1")
```

Comment: Can't you assign a `self.passenger_hotel_choice` which you set to true of false once you know their choice? Then you could simply retrieve `c.passenger_hotel_choice` for example. By the way, catching all exceptions with `except Exception` is bad practice since you don't know how you should react. You also don't need the `break` statements since the `status = False` already gets you out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class attribute, then you can just check using `if c.hotel_check_input == 'yes'`.

Comment: Thanks man :)  i had an evergreen ship stuck in my brain couldnt think of anything